# An Algorithm to determine the minimum number of points that cover some given points with radius R

Tags: algorithms

There are some given points. And I want to locate some facilities in continuous space to cover the points as mentioned earlier. In my problem, I define a facility covers a point; if it is inside a circle around that point with radius R. I want to determine the minimum number of points that are needed to cover all the given points.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by *covering*? How many points should lie on the circle?

Comment: I define a facility covers a point with radius R if that point is inside a circle around that facility with radius R.
 I want to develope an algorithm that determines minimum number  of facilities that must locate to cover some given points with radius R. So I cann't determine how many points should lie on the circle, but I can say based on the definition of coverage, at least one point must lie on a circle.

Comment: Just take the two points that are the farthest apart to be ends of the diameter.

Comment: radius R as coverage criteria is given and I shouldn't determine it. In more detail, R and some points are the inputs of an algorithm that I want to develop.

Comment: Okay, so you basically want to determine the minimum number of *circles* with a fixed radius and the positions of their centers. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, exactly...

Answer (score 0):

This is not the most efficient method, but just an idea on how you could approach this.

Let’s say you have $n$ points, and $f(n,R)$ is the required minimum number of circles needed to cover $n$ points with circles of radius $R$. Define $p_i$ to be the average point of $i$ points taken all at once, where $1 \leq i \leq n$. So, the coordinates of $p_i$ will be $$\left( \frac 1i \sum_{k=1}^i x_k  \ ,\ \frac 1i \sum_{k=1}^i y_k \right)$$ where $x_k, y_k$ are the coordinates of the $k^{th}$ given point.

Calculate $p_i$ for every $i$ ranging from $1$ to $n$. (*Note that there may be multiple possibilities for $p_i$ depending on **which** $i$ points you choose. Particularly, $n \choose i$ possibilities*). Now, construct a circle of radius $R$ centered at $p_i$ in each case, and note the number of points it encloses. The case where the maximum points (say, $H$) are enclosed is what we’re interested in (if there is more than one case, include that for further calculations too). Then we have 
$$ f(n,R) = 1 + f(n-H, R) $$

And then maybe you could work with this recursion to get the answer. This will involve a huge number of iterations, but I can’t think of any better way for now.